# OAuth Consent Screen URL bar missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have submitted an app for Verification on google cloud platform.
which has been published successfully on google chrome store.

Google provided feedback regarding verification process:

Below mentioned **outstanding item**:

> The app project client_id in the URL bar of the OAuth Consent Screen/Permissions Page
> is not shown.
>
> **Issue:**
> The issue is URL bar is not visible on consent screen i.e Identity API Scope Approval UI.

I had removed all the permissions (from Google account which I used to sign in chrome) and even deleted the cookies still the URL bar was not visible on consent screen i.e Identity API Scope Approval UI.

I am using Version 89.0.4389.90 (Official Build) (64-bit) chrome browser.

Could anyone please explain the root cause behind url not coming on Oauth screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to right click the window of the OAuth screen and select "Show as tab" to see the full URL.